# How to Stop Execute Code after Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here,i don't understand,after response why rest of code is executing. Please help,if i am wrong at any point. so i want to stop executing call after response,how can i do it because unnecessarily hit to database and i think if code is executing,no benefit of response handler is there

My response handler is

```
var responseHandler = function(res,responseObject,message,error,status){
  console.log(responseObject)
  console.log(status)
  res.status(status).send({
    "error":error,
    "message":message,
    "response":responseObject
  })
  res.end();
}

module.exports.responseHandler = responseHandler;
```

below, after error, i am responding,but console.log is also working.so i wrote database call there,then it will also execute.so there is misunderstanding here

```
registrationObj.save(function(err,registrationObj){
  if(err){
    configurationHolder.ResponseUtil.responseHandler(res,null,configurationHolder.errorMessage.failedAuthorization,true,401);
    console.log("printing");
  } else {
    next(null, registrationObj);
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the piece where you are talking with the database? Or add a comment? Right now it's not really clear where the problem is.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni thanks for response, i modified question,please check it out

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you asking why the code outside of your `responseHandler` carries on running after you've called `res.end();`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes,after res.end(),console.log is running,why?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, calling `.end()` just signals to the server that you're done sending data to the client.  It doesn't actually stop server side processing - if you want to stop executing further code, you'll need to put logic in place (perhaps return something from `responseHandler`?) to tell the rest of _your_ code that you're done, so it can stop.

Comment: @JamesThorpe you're correct :)